# Ubuntu 18.04: Slow shutdown

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, restart

After a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I am experiencing very slow shutdowns , When I press <kbd>esc</kbd> the following are shown .

"A stop job is running for IIO sensor Proxy service (s /1min 32s)"

Gradually the time is increased. Are there any other people experiencing this ? What could be the reason behind this ?

Comment: sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove iio-sensor-proxy; find /proc /sys | grep -ie brightness -e light -e lux -e lumin; sudo modprobe -a tsl2550 isl29003 isl29020 apds9802als apds990x

Comment: You can adjust the time systemd will wait for the process to be killed. Check this answer how to do that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273876/a-stop-job-is-running-for-session-c2-of-user/410622

Comment: There is another possible way to solve this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076518/iio-sensor-proxy-service-hangs-on-shutdown

Comment: I found the following on askubuntu.com https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076518/iio-sensor-proxy-service-hangs-on-shutdown

Answer (score 2):

Your long shutdowns are caused by a possible unresponsive ambient light sensor D-Bus proxy. You can find some information on the GNOME website [here](https://developer.gnome.org/iio-sensor-proxy/1.0/gdbus-net.hadess.SensorProxy.html). If you can live without needing an accelerator or ambient light sensor on your computer, just uninstall it using `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove iio-sensor-proxy`. If this is a laptop like a Lenovo Yoga, where an accelerator might be used to see if the device should be in "tablet mode" this might have been automatically installed while Ubuntu was looking for drivers. Another option, if you still want to use the accelerator, is to kill the task after a certain amount of time. To do that i would try `timeout KILL_TIME ~/FILE`.