# IIO sensor Proxy service hangs on shutdown

Tags: grub2, shutdown, brightness

[image: The error]

A week back on a shutdown I got this error. And after that my brightness keys don't work anymore. Also I seem to get some random seconds long freezes every now and then since this. But I'm not sure if that's related.

Can I fix this?
Just running `iio-sensor-proxy` doesn't seem to do anything.

If that doesn't work can I safely uninstall it and how?

I just want my brightness keys back.
I have played around with `acpi_backlight=vendor` and `video`. `grub-update`, `grub-update2` those seem to help in any way.

From what I understand it's a [driver for the accelerometer](https://github.com/hadess/iio-sensor-proxy) and My laptop doesn't have one (and I don't really care about rotating my screen....)

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem on my HP laptop too: the laptop took way too long to shut down. I didn't uninstall the package just masked the service not to start up on boot:

```
sudo systemctl mask iio-sensor-proxy.service
```

then also disable the orientation plugin (which is the only one using the accelerometer):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.orientation active false
```

You will not have this long shutdown problem any more *after* your second reboot.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `dconf` can you explain more how to use that?

Comment: Ok, another way you can use the `gsettings` tool execute this command on console :  `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.orientation active  false`

Comment: Fer: Please see [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1077859/revisions) and upvote! **:-)** Please always ensure all of the information is in your answer, not hidden in the comments!  **;-)**  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, keep up the good work.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. But it is really hard to check.